# How to not generate Instance IDs with Firebase on-device text recognition?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-mlkit, text-recognition

I want to use the ML Kit for Firebase to recognize text on iOS devices.
I don't want to collect data and process personal data, so I don't use cloud-based models, only on-device models.
The Firebase documentation, "Privacy and Security in Firebase" states that the ML Kit for Firebase handles Instance IDs.
When using only the device model, how do I prevent the Instance ID from being generated and sent to Google?

The settings for my app are:

**Cartfile**

```
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseAnalyticsBinary.json" == 6.17.0
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseMLVisionBinary.json" == 6.17.0
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseMLVisionTextModelBinary.json" == 6.17.0
```

I did unlink the FirebaseCoreDiagnostics from my app.

**Info.plist**

```
<key>FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED</key>
<true/>
<key>GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_IDFV_COLLECTION_ENABLED</key>
<false/>
<key>FirebaseDataCollectionDefaultEnabled</key>
<false/>
<key>FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

**Swift**

```
import Firebase
```

```
private lazy var vision = Vision.vision()
```

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
vision.isStatsCollectionEnabled = false
let onDeviceTextRecognizer = vision.onDeviceTextRecognizer()
...
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: If you need information about how ML Kit works internally and could use a firm statement about its privacy and security policies, you should contact Firebase support directly with those questions.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I asked Firebase support.